# Vuetify errors when loading a Vue-generated web component into a host/parent that is also a Vue app

Tags: vue.js, web-component, vuetify.js

I have a Vue Cli 3 generated web component/custom element that uses Vuetify.  I have a parent/host Vue App that is also using Vuetify. When the custom element loads into the host app, I get a bunch of Type errors as shown in the screenshot.  e.g. Type Error: Cannot read property theme of undefined.

This appears to be a Vuetify issue. What is the correct architecture for using Vuetify within a Vue CLi custom element and in its host application?

Currently, I have Vue.js script tag in parent, for use by the custom element. And Vue is imported into the Vue app, as normal.  Script tag is there only because the custom element requires it. I have Vuetify included in both as well.  The web component is using the vuetify plugin. And so is the host.

The web component runs perfectly fine on its own, and so does the host app.  So, apparently there are conflicts.

Thanks!
Donnie

[image]

Comment: Note that this may be related to the hoops I had to jump through to get Vuetify to work inside the component ... posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467240/how-do-you-include-vuetify-inside-web-component

Comment: This is one of the more common errors I see too 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'rtl' of undefined

Comment: looks like this.$vuetify is undefined in the web component only when it is included in host app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this myself.  In short, you cannot use the Vuetify plugin and the al-a-cart.  It only works if you include the full Vue and Vuetify inside the web component.  Not optimal, but at least it is a workaround for this Vuetify bug.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
Vue.use(Vuetify);
// import { VApp,VToolbar,VToolbarTitle,VSpacer,VContainer,VLayout,VFlex,VCard,VCardTitle,VCardActions,VBtn,VDivider } from 'vuetify/lib';
export default {
  /* components:{
      VApp,VToolbar,VToolbarTitle,VSpacer,VContainer,VLayout,VFlex,VCard,VCardTitle,VCardActions,VBtn,VDivider
    }  */
}
```

Comment: hey i am having the same issue but cant get it working with your solution